# Error : Value cannot be null. Parameter name : path 1, when add a new Azure Mobile Apps table Controller

Tags: xamarin.forms, controller, azure-mobile-services

It's the first time I create a back end for my Xamarin.Forms application. I follow instructions on `Azure Portal -> Quick-Start`, create a data connection, `choose c# in step 2` and `download the project`.

Build it and now I want to add a new table. So :

- I add the class in DataObjects folder.
- I add the line in the Context file : `public DbSet<Coffee> Coffees{ get; set; }`
- And when I try to add the Azure Mobile Apps table controller, an error message tell me :

  ```
      Value cannot be null. Parameter name : path1.
  ```

What can I do to fix that ?

Sorry for my bad English.

Have a nice day!

Comment: two years later and totally unrelated, the same error message starts to appear for me in a pure c++ project after upgrading to vs2019 v16.10.1; most often after switching the solution configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, and the problem is also mentioned on the Visual Studio Development community: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/563354/adding-a-new-azure-mobile-apps-table-controller-or.html

Meanwhile you can work around the problem by creating the controller in code. I've tested the following steps for a Azure Mobile Apps Table Controller for a Xamarin Forms app:

1. Add a new class to the Controllers folder, i.e. {YourDataObject}Controller.cs
2. Take an existing and working controller and copy the code into the new controller file.
3. Replace *{OldMobileAppName}Service* and *{OldMobileAppName}Context* with *{NewMobileAppName}Service* and *{NewMobileAppName}Context*
4. Replace *{OldDataObjectName}* with *{NewDataObjectName}*

Finally publish your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring a Table Controller requires three steps:

1. Create a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class.
2. Configure a table reference in the Mobile DbContext class.
3. Create a table controller.

A Data Transfer Object (DTO) is a plain C# object that inherits from EntityData. An example from the documentation:

```
public class TodoItem : EntityData
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Complete {get; set;}
}
```

Please reference this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/howto/server/dotnet-framework#define-a-table-controller) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did, and it's this documentation I followed